# Using trunc function in python

Tags: python

I have the mathematical formula which looks like this:

[image]

I want to convert it into 2.7 python syntax.
I assumed upper "trunc" has to be the same thing as math.trunc:

```
a = (x - 360)*math.trunc(x/360)
```

Is this the correct python 2.7 syntax?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? Have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.trunc)?

Comment: I tried it, but I do not know if the result is correct or not.
Yes I took a look at that page too, but I do not understand the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You translated the formula incorrectly. You don't need parentheses around `x - 360`, also you can use Python integer division instead of `math.trunc`:

```
a = x - 360 * (x // 360)
```

Note that it works even for negative `x` unlike `math.trunc`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran:

```
from __future__ import division
import math

for i in xrange(0, 1080, 1):
   print i, math.trunc(i/360)
```

Seemed to give the right answer.

You will want to use `from __future__ import division` to force Python 3 style division (see here for more details: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238).

Comment: `//` is integer division, so you definitely don't want to use it.

Comment: Oops...wrong way round. I'll fix it. Thanks @DavidZwicker